# Comma Code (Python)

Tags: python, beginner

This is a practice from "Automate the boring stuff with Python".

My code works, but after checking out some other solutions on the Internet my solution looks more basic, and I can't tell if that's a good thing or not and if I got the right lessons from this chapter.

This is the code:

```
def items(someList):
    stringEnd = str(someList[-1])
    del someList[-1]
    str1 = ', '.join(someList)
    new_string = ''
    new_string = str1 + ' and' + ' ' + stringEnd
    return(new_string)

spam = ['apples', 'kittens', 'tofu', 'puppies']
print(items(spam))
```

Any feedback will be really appreciated!

Here is what the book required:

> Write a function that takes a list value as an argument and returns a string with all the items separated by a comma and a space, with and inserted before the last item. For example, passing the previous spam list to the function would return 'apples, bananas, tofu, and cats'. But your function should be able to work with any list value passed to it.

Comment: You might be interested in this [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/177394/comma-code-project-from-automate-the-boring-stuff-with-python/177396#177396). This code sounded familiar to me for some reason :)

Comment: A bit of context about what this code is supposed to do would help us :)

Comment: @MrGrj Added more info to the OP! :)

Comment: I suspect there's no comma between `tofu` and `cats`, is it?

Comment: @MrGrj Definitely not.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is pretty straightforward, and your solution is as well. I have only a couple of small comments:

1. The `pop` method in Python removes and returns the last item in a list, which can replace two lines.
2. You don't have to `new_string = ''` when you set `new_string` on the next line. As a result, things can be shortened a bit.
3. Personally, since `str1` is only used once, I would personally just do it inline and not save it to a variable. The only time I save something to a variable, if it is only used once, is to shorten an otherwise-long line.
4. Concatenating two hard-coded strings should be put in one operation (i.e. `' and' + ' '` => `' and '`
5. Guards! [They're the best way to check input before executing.](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1149121&seqNum=11)

My recommended version:

```
def items(some_list):
    if not some_list:
        return ''

    string_end = some_list.pop()
    if not some_list:
        return string_end

    and_display = ' and ' if len(some_list) == 1 else ', and '
    new_string = ', '.join(some_list) + and_display + string_end
    return new_string

print(items(['apples', 'kittens', 'tofu', 'puppies']))
```

This works fine as long as you are working with a list of strings. It will crash if you pass in an int or something that can't auto-convert to a string. That may or may not be a problem, depending on your perspective.  Trying to make your code auto-convert things to strings, if they aren't strings, can be a very error-prone process. As a result, I think it is perfectly fine to write this the easy way, and let it be the developer's problem if it crashes due to non-string arguments.

Docstrings are usually helpful for this kind of thing.

**Note on pass-by-reference**

Hat tip to TheEspinosa: Python uses a pass-by-reference style for its arguments. As a result, modifying arguments (which is especially easy for lists, as is the case here) can result in unintentional side-effects. The use of `pop` (or `del` in your original code) results in the last entry being removed from the list, not just inside the function, but also in the variable passed in to the function. For your example usage, which calls this function with a constant value, this behavior doesn't matter. But it may as part of a larger application. There are three ways to handle this:

1. Adjust your algorithm so you don't make any changes to any arguments being passed in (@Richard Nemann's answer works that way)
2. Copy the list before using it inside your function. A simple shorthand to copy a list is: `new_copy = old_copy[:]`. There is also a [copy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) module.
3. Ignore it and let it be the caller's problem.

I use all three solutions depending on the circumstances or my mood. A copy operation obviously involves some overhead, but unless you know that performance is a problem, I would still do a copy if the algorithm that avoids the need for the copy is harder to understand.

To be clear about the problem the current code can potentially introduce, try running my implementation (or yours) like this:

```
vals = ['apples', 'bananas', 'grapes']
items(vals)
print(len(vals))
```

If you run this code the last line will print `2`, because in your calling scope the variable has been modified-by-reference: grapes is no longer in the list.

I said at the beginning that this was a straightforward problem. At this point in time though I think it's fair to say that the devil is in the details :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback!

This pop method wasn't in the chapter at all and I tried to use the information in the book for this code. The only non-book thing I used is ' '.join.

Comment: Variable names should be `snake_case` instead of `camelCase` in python [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions)

Comment: @SloppyCoder I missed one more small point which I just added

Comment: Haha, thanks Conor! A bunch of thanks to all who contributed, this is exactly the things I was looking for.

Comment: @SloppyCoder I've added some guard conditions.  The guards could probably be simplified, but I'm a big fan of clear guard conditions.

Comment: Good call on the removal of the `str`. I think it's good to mention python's duck typing concept here. You shouldn't have to worry about forcing things you think should look like strings to be strings. Ideally they should already act like a string.

Comment: Whenever *easily* possible, I would prefer a function that does not change state. So  I would avoid `list.pop()` and `del list[-1]`

Comment: The question *does* ask for the Oxford comma. OP (and your answer) simply implemented the specification wrongly. That said, this is awkward if there are only two items in the list: even ardent users of the Oxford comma would omit it in the construct “apples, and bananas”.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thanks: when I posted my answer the book question wasn't in his question: it got added later, so I based my answer off of his.

Comment: @gerrit I was counting in trinary?

Comment: -1 for basing whether you modifying the caller's data based on your mood. Modifying the caller's data is something that should be done *very* sparingly. In this case, you also make an assumption about the caller's type; if I pass in a generator or `tuple`, your code breaks.

Comment: @KonradRudolph The [Oxford comma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma) only applies to lists with 3 or more elements by definition. “apples, and bananas” is not a use of the Oxford comma; it is simply incorrect punctuation. The book's problem statement does not make any explicit notes about what to do when there are only two elements, just as it makes no notes about a single element. The most reasonable assumptions would be to follow English rules or not support those inputs and throw a `ValueError` error.

Comment: `because in your calling scope the variable has been modified-by-reference` This is misleading and unprecise at best. The variable has not been changed, but the object the variable refers to. The parameter contains an object reference which is passed by value.

Answer (score 17):

Your problem can be reduced to:

```
def list_english(items):
    """Returns a comma-separated string of the list's items,
    separating the last item with an 'and'.
    """
    if not items:
        return ''

    if len(items) == 1:
        return items[0]

    return '{}, and {}'.format(', '.join(items[:-1]), items[-1])
```

Note that variable and function names in python are to be named with underscore-separated lower-case according to PEP 8.
Also consider using docstrings to state, what a function's purpose is.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(list_english(['apples', 'kittens', 'tofu', 'puppies']))
```

Also enclose your script code in an `if __name__ == '__main__':` block to prevent it from being run if the module is solely imported.

Finally, consider your variable naming. Python has dynamic typing, so expressive names are especially important.

Comment: I might suggest inverting your first conditional.  You've basically got all your code inside an if condition, which is always returned from, and a return '' at the end.  Better to: `if not items: return ''` at the top and then un-indent what is the meat of your application.  Basically, use a more standard guard clause.

Comment: (a) Using `.join()` to combine three strings seems very unpleasant to me; this is what `+` is for. (b) I suggest making the second conditional `if len(items)==1`. After all, that's what you really care about, you just haven't admitted it to the reader. Then all the logic for the final case can be written on one line (no need for `head` variable).

Comment: Unless you are doing the join in a loop that runs for billions of iterations, the performance difference is insignificant; this is classic premature optimisation. I agree that it would be bad to join a variable number of strings with `+` though.

Comment: You need a `len(items) == 2` case.

Comment: `list_english(['a', 'b'])` -> `a, and b`, who would want this?

Comment: The OP to comply with the respective task. See also "Oxford comma".

Comment: @RichardNeumann I think the main problem is that the book-question is unclear.  Normally, an oxford comma is only relevant to lists of 3 or more: regardless of what "type" of comma you use, it is not standard practice to put a comma in a list of two.  The distinction only comes with 3 or more.  For oxford, include the comma.  Otherwise, don't.  However, the way the book-question is worded suggests that there should always be a comma, even for a list of two.  As a result, your answer solves the problem, but Jared's is also correct in saying that this is never proper english.

Comment: Does this work if a pass a generator? Would `len` consume the elements?

Comment: @jpmc26  - Nope raises a `TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()` - You could write one, but the simplest methods would indeed consume the generator.

Comment: @ConorMancone Not just normally, but [by definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma). I think really the book's problem statement just doesn't specify what should happen in cases where there are less than 3 elements. Note that it doesn't call out an empty or single element list, either. In my opinion, raising `ValueError` in those cases would be equally valid given *only* the book's problem statement.

Comment: @jpmc26 Indeed.  I'm still amused that what initially seemed like a simple problem has turned out to have quite a number of details to watch out for.  I suspect that this was neither a great example on the part of this book, nor well executed.

Comment: @ConorMancone I might've been amused the first time I saw one of those on SO, but I now see them come up with enough regularity that I'm sick of them. lol. They're such a waste of time because usually the OP never even comes back and clarifies. (In this case, they can't since the problem is from a book.) So it's a dice roll at who guesses right about the details.

Comment: @jpmc26 That's a true story, although it doesn't bother me from a big picture perspective.  In this case the OP has been involved a few times since originally posting the question (hit-and-run OPs are the ones that bug me).  It sounds like he is only doing it for his own learning purposes, in which case the extending discussion in both the answers and comments section are probably more useful than figuring out exactly how to answer the book anyway.

Comment: Well done for solving the problem on your own, but this doesn't seem like code review to me. Outside of some fairly basic stylistic issues, you didn't comment on the OP's code, discuss their mistakes or direct them on how to come up with a solution like yours. You just wrote a completely different function which solved the same problem.